# AJAX form $('form')[0].reset(); on submit not clearing values. What am I missing?

Tags: ajax, forms, reset, submit-button

thank you in advance for any help given.  I'm just learning jQuery and AJAX and would appreciate some help with the following code.  All validation rules work, the form submits and the page does not refresh.  The problem is that the form values are not clearing/resetting to default after the submit has triggered.  Thoughts?

**********EDITED to include HTML markup*************

```
        <div id="form">
            <h1 class="title">Contact Us</h1><!-- title ends -->
            <p class="contactUs">Ask about our services and request a quote today!</p><!-- contactUs ends -->

            <div id="success"><p>Your message was sent successfully.  Thank you.</p></div>

                <p id="required">* All fields required.</p>

                    <form name="form" id="contactMe" method="post" action="process.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input class="txt" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" required name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>" placeholder="Name" />
                            <div id="nameError"><p>Your name is required.</p></div>
                        <input class="txt" type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" required name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>" placeholder="Email Address" />
                            <div id="emailError"><p>A valid email address is required.</p></div>
                        <textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="40" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <div id="messageError"><p>A message is required.</p></div>
                        <input type="hidden" maxlength="80" size="50" id="complete" name="complete" placeholder="Please Keep This Field Empty" />
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" />
                <input type="reset" value="RESET" name="reset" />
        </form>
        </div><!-- form ends -->




//hide form submit success message by default.  to be shown on successfull ajax submission only. 
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#success').is(':visible')){
        $(this).hide()
        }
});


//form validation
function validateForm() {

//name
var a=document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
if (a==null || a=="")
  {
      $('#nameError').fadeIn(250);
  return false;
  }

//email address
var c=document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
var atpos=c.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=c.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=c.length)
  {
      $('#emailError').fadeIn(250);
  return false;
  }

//message
var e=document.forms["form"]["message"].value;
if (e==null || e=="")
  {
      $('#messageError').fadeIn(250);
  return false;
  }
}//javascript form validation ends


//ajax submit and clear form on success
$(function () {


    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        var myForm = validateForm();                

        if (myForm == false){
            e.preventDefault();//stop submission for safari if fields empty
        }
        else{

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $('#success').fadeIn(250);
                if ($('#nameError, #emailError, #messageError').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#nameError, #emailError, #messageError').fadeOut(250);
                    }
                $('form')[0].reset();//clear form after submit success
            }//success ends
          });//ajax ends
        e.preventDefault();//prevent default page refresh
        }//else ends
        });//submit ends

});//function ends

//if reset button is clicked AND messages displayed, remove all form html messages
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form input[type="reset"]').click(function() {
        if ($('#success, #nameError, #emailError, #messageError').is(':visible')) {
            $('#success, #nameError, #emailError, #messageError').fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any elements with `id="reset"` or `name="reset"`? How many `form` tags are on the page?

Comment: Yes @KevinB I do have name="reset" in the markup.  I have edited my post and included all the form markup above the js.

Comment: Change it from reset to something else.

Comment: Never give name or id attributes values to elements that equal submit, reset, or any other method name that can be found on a dom element.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for the help.  I changed the name of the reset button in the markup to "clearForm" and adjusted my js to match.  Must have been a conflict as "reset" is a reserved word in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By giving your input `id="reset"` and/or `name="reset"`, you effectively overwrote the `form.reset` method of the form because by doing so you made `form.reset` target the reset button. Simply give it a different id and name value.

Never give elements name or id attributes that equal the name of a property of a dom node.

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Would vote this up but my rep is currently too low.